# Automation to detect untagged resources in AWS

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, tags, jq, aws-cli

I am trying to run api call to find the list of AWS resources that dont have correct tags and get the output into json file:

Name: "Unused"
Name in Resolve = false

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tags-er-page 100 | jq '.ResourceTagMappingList{} | select(contains({Tags: [{Key: "Name"}, [{Key: "Name in Resolve"}]}))' > tag.json
```

But, it gives the list of all the tags along with tag "Name" and "Name in Resolve". I want to filter the output with only those 2 tags with its values

Actual Results:

```
{
 "ResourceARN":"arn:aws:backup:$Region:$AccountId:recovery-point:xxxxxxxx",
 "Tags": [
  {
   "Key: "Name",
   "Value": "eks-efs-non-prod"
  },
  {
   "Key": "Deptt"
   "Value": "XXX"
  },
  {
   "Key": "BusinessUnit"
   "Value": "XXX"
  },
  {
   "Key": "Name in Resolve"
   "Value": "True"
  },
  {
   "Key": "SysOwner"
   "Value": "XXX"
  },
  {
   "Key": "IT Director"
   "Value": "Ankur K"
  }
 ]
}
{
 "ResourceARN":"arn:aws:backup:$Region:$AccountId:recovery-point:xxxxxxxx",
 "Tags": [
  {
   "Key: "Name",
   "Value": "Unused"
  },
  {
   "Key": "Deptt"
   "Value": "XXX"
  },
  {
   "Key": "BusinessUnit"
   "Value": "XXX"
  },
  {
   "Key": "Name in Resolve"
   "Value": "false"
  },
 {
   "Key": "SysOwner"
   "Value": "XXX"
  },
  {
   "Key": "IT Director"
   "Value": "Ankur K"
  }
 ]
}
```

Expected Results:

```
{
 "ResourceARN":"arn:aws:backup:$Region:$AccountId:recovery-point:xxxxxxxx",
 "Tags": [
  {
   "Key: "Name",
   "Value": "eks-efs-non-prod"
  },
  {
   "Key": "Name in Resolve"
   "Value": "True"
  }
 ]
}
{
 "ResourceARN":"arn:aws:backup:$Region:$AccountId:recovery-point:xxxxxxxx",
 "Tags": [
  {
   "Key: "Name",
   "Value": "Unused"
  },
  {
   "Key": "Name in Resolve"
   "Value": "false"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Which AWS resources are you referring to. AWS has many services and many resources.

Comment: This is for all those aws services that have missing tags with its tag name and its value

Comment: 1. The JSON you showed is not quite valid. Also, it would be helpful to see some further details about the result of the aws command.  2. The jq command shown is also (obviously) invalid.  Is that the result of a typo?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide provide the input that should result in the output you provided, as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON sample has some small errors, but using it (with corrections) as input, the relevant jq filter would be:

```
.Tags |= map(select(.Key | IN("Name", "Name in Resolve")))
```

If your jq does not have `IN/1`, then you could simply copy its def into the beginning of your program:

```
def IN(s): first((s == .) // empty) // false;
```

Comment: I tried running like this ```aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tags-per-page 100 | jq '.Tags |= map(select(.Key | IN("Name", "Name in Resolve")))' > tag.json``` but it throws an error

Comment: The program I gave works on the JSON you showed, not the result of the `aws` command, as you did not give those details.